# is there an easy way to calculate between two coordinates in android - java?

Tags: java, android, gps, coordinates

I hope if someone could help me...
I want to have/make a function that if I put 2 coordinates (longtitude1, longtitude2, latitude1, latitude2)
I will have the distance in meters!

couldnt find if its already exist or not... but Im NOT using googlemaps or stuff like that

Comment: Use a search engine to search for `calculate distance latitude longitude`. Or, use [the `distanceBetween()` method on `Location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29).

Comment: http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf

Comment: What do you want to calculate; The distance or a sequence of points inbetween the coordinates, or what else? (There is a missing word between the word "calculate" and "between".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the `distanceTo()` method. What you do is create two locations, then use that method to calculate the distance between them. This does give you the result in meters. It would look like this:

```
Location location1 = new Location("first location");    
location1.setLatitude(latitude1);
location1.setLongitude(longtitude1);

Location location2 = new Location("second location");
location2.setLatitude(latitude2);
location2.setLongitude(longtitude2);

float distanceBetween = location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but it asks for a "float" but when eclipse tells me the data i put is double and not float...

how can I pass that? because then I cant do "set latitude" or "set longtitude"

Comment: @shine `latitude` and `longtitude` should both be `double`'s... are they? If not, you need to convert them to doubles.

Comment: well it dosent give me the distance in meters...
should I do somthing with the number I am reciveing to make it into meters?

Comment: @shine It should be in meters; [the docs for distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) say `Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location.`.

Comment: @hichris...thank you! I found out... just If i need to work with it, I must do Math.Round first...


thank you!